# Unit testing of custom Assert function using Google Test

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost, googletest

I am using Boost.Assert library, and have this custom assert code, which needs to be unit tested using Google Test framework:

```cpp
    #include <boost/assert.hpp>
    #define ASSERT(expr)                BOOST_ASSERT(expr)
    #define ASSERT_MSG(expr, msg)       BOOST_ASSERT_MSG(expr, msg)

    namespace boost {
        inline void assertion_failed_msg(char const* expr, char const* msg, char const* function, char const* /*file*/, long /*line*/) {
            std::cerr << "Expression '" << expr << "' is false in function '" << function << "': " << (msg ? msg : "<...>") << ".\n"
                << "Backtrace:\n" << boost::stacktrace::stacktrace() << std::endl;

            std::abort();
        }

        inline void assertion_failed(char const* expr, char const* function, char const* file, long line) {
            ::boost::assertion_failed_msg(expr, 0 /*nullptr*/, function, file, line);
        }
    } // namespace boost
```

The idea is to check that `ASSERT( 1!=1 )` terminates the program with the appropriate error code and error log message.

I am aware of Google Test, Death Tests. I have the following structure, which kind of works for me:

```cpp
void assert_death_test() 
{
    ASSERT( 1!=1 );
}

TEST(unit_test_DeathTest, test_of_assert_function) {
    EXPECT_EXIT(assert_death_test(), ::testing::KilledBySignal(SIGABRT), "Stuff hit the fan.");
}
```

Since I'm using a death test, `ASSERT(...)` does not terminate unit testing, and death test notices that the program exits with some log message. The problem is this:

```
Death test: assert_death_test()
    Result: died but not with expected error.
  Expected: contains regular expression "Stuff hit the fan."
Actual msg:
[  DEATH   ] Expression '1!=1' is false in function 'void assert_death_test()': <...>.
[  DEATH   ] Backtrace:
[  DEATH   ]  0# boost::assertion_failed_msg(char const*, char const*, char const*, char const*, long) in ./executable
[  DEATH   ]  1# boost::assertion_failed(char const*, char const*, char const*, long) in ./executable
[  DEATH   ]  2# assert_death_test() in ./executable
[  DEATH   ]  3# unit_test_DeathTest_test_of_assert_function_Test::TestBody() in ./executable
.
. // Continues with more log messages
.
```

Because of this problem, the test is counted as a fail, whereas it normally is a success. (The assert kills program, and sends a log message to stdout)

How can I solve this problem? (Alternative methods are also applicable)

Is there a way to force the output of a test to be successful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved with the following line:

```
EXPECT_DEATH(assert_death_test(), "Expression '.*");
```

My main issue was not creating a vaild regex string, as pointed out by @Quarra.

`EXPECT_DEATH` is also more appropriate, as `ASSERT(...)` kills the program.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting an expectation that `"Stuff hit the fan."` will be logged at program exit but your assertion doesn't have any message so this might be the problem here. The test fails because you're expecting a custom message to be logged which is not added there. Please try:

```
void assert_death_test() 
{
    ASSERT( 1!=1,  "Stuff hit the fan.");
}
```

As you're implementing a custom message here, I'd also add this to the expected output, i.e. the expected string should also contain `"Expression '"`...

Comment: My assertion does have a message, it calls the `assertion_failed_msg()` function as assertion fails. This is how boost.assert works. The assertion message does not fit the expectation, that I agree. I can't seem to make them match either, another problem arises in that case.

Comment: The test fails because you expect that `"Stuff hit the fan."` should be logged; this particular string is NOT used anywhere - that's why you see `Result: died but not with expected error.` which means assertion happens (as it should) but without required string. You must add the required assertion string and then expect it to be logged. In other words: why would `"Stuff hit the fan."` be anywhere in the backtrace if it is not used by you in `assert_death_test`? This is user-provided log message, and it is nowhere in the `arrange` part of your test-case (see arrange-act-assert).